# Reading a csv file in C and accessing a value into a 2-dimensions array

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, indexing

I'm just starting C programming, and I have a project to code for school. The purpose of the project is to assign families to different days for a festival. This assignment must meet certain constraints (numbers of people at each day of the festival for instance). We have at our disposal a csv file of this form:

```
family_size;preference1;preference2;preference3;preference4;preference5
3; 6; 4; 3; 2; 0
3; 3; 1; 0; 2; 4
4; 3; 2; 0; 6; 4
3; 4; 5; 1; 0; 3
8; 2; 0; 5; 1; 6
5; 1; 0; 4; 6; 2
```

In order to implement the different assignment functions, the constraints and the objective function, I decided to store the information contained in the csv file into a 2-dimensional array that I named matrix. Thus, I could access in this matrix the information of the csv file (number of people per family and preferences of each family in terms of day).

For this, here is the function I have implemented (I don't store the headers in my matrix):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <float.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000
#define MAX_NUM_VALUES 6

int read_csv_file(char *filename, int matrix[][MAX_NUM_VALUES], int *num_rows) {

    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int row = 0, col = 0;

    // open the file for reading
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    // count the number of rows in the file
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        (*num_rows)++;
    }

    // reset file pointer to the beginning of the file
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // ignore the first line of the file
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp);

    // store the values from the file into the matrix
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(line, ";");
        col = 0;
        while (token != NULL && col < MAX_NUM_VALUES) {
            matrix[row][col++] = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
        row++;
    }

    // close the file
    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

But here is my first problem. I can't access the values of my matrix correctly.

I don't see what I have misunderstood and I would need your help.

Because in my function that is supposed to assign a day to each family by choosing one among the different preferences that the family has issued, my function 'choose_random_numbers' (see below) sometimes assigns a family on a day that does not appear in these wishes.

```
void choose_random_numbers(int matrix[][MAX_NUM_VALUES], int num_rows, int *random_numbers, int *count_days) {

    int satisfied = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (!satisfied) {

        // Reset count_days to zero
        memset(count_days, 0, sizeof(int)*7);

        for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
            // choose random index from 1 to 5
            int rand_index = rand() % (MAX_NUM_VALUES - 1) + 1;
            
            int day = matrix[i][rand_index];
            random_numbers[i] = day;
        
            for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                if (day == matrix[i][j]) {
                    satisfied = 1;
                }
                else{
                satisfied = 0;
                }
            }

            count_days[day]+=matrix[i][0];
        }

        satisfied = 1;
          
        printf("test: %d", matrix[5][2]);


}
```

And here it is an overview of my main:

```
int main() {

    char *filename = "pb40.csv";
    int num_rows = 0;
    int matrix[MAX_LINE_LENGTH][MAX_NUM_VALUES];

    if (!read_csv_file(filename, matrix, &num_rows)) {
        return 1;
    }
    int random_numbers[MAX_NUM_VALUES];
    int count_days[7];

    choose_random_numbers(matrix, num_rows, random_numbers, count_days);
   

    return 0;
}
```

And when I print the content of matrix[5][~] in my choose_random_numbers(), it prints me differents numbers each time...

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This looks a bit advanced for a starter project...

Comment: I'm not a beginner in programming in general but it's the first time I code in C.

Comment: First of all, thank you for not using `scanf`.  Could you post the relevant parts of `main` as well?

Comment: Yes I just edited my post adding it

Answer (score 3):

Your `read_csv_file` works fine but you have simply mistaken the ordering of rows and columns:

- `matrix[4][3]` is `5`
- `matrix[3][4]` is `0`.

This is because of the [row-major ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) in arrays in C (and C++) unlike some other languages that uses column-major ordering.

It helps to think of it as-if the Y axis is the first subscript operator and the X axis is the second:

```c
matrix[Yval][Xval]
```

or

| Y\X | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | `[0][1]` 6 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | `[1][0]` 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 6 | `[2][5]` **4** |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | `[3][4]` **0** | 3 |
| 4 | 8 | 2 | 0 | `[4][3]` **5** | 1 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | `[5][2]` **0** | 4 | 6 | 2 |

---

Notes:

- `read_csv_file` should take `filename` as a `const char*`. You are not aiming to change the content of `filename`.
- Instead of first reading through the whole file to calculate `num_rows`, you could just set it after you've read through the file normally. You've counted the rows using `rows` so `*num_rows = row` before `return 1;` should do it (or `*num_rows = row + 1;` if you want to include the header in the count like you do now). That way you don't have to read the file twice and you don't have to `fseek`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think that my problem doesn't come from a mistake about row and column order. Indeed, as you can see below: When I `printf("test: %d", matrix[5][2]);`, my program doesn't print 0 as it should be. <br> But something interesting that I had'nt notice is that my program doesn't return the same value for matrix[5][2] when I run it several times. So maybe there is something in my code that change the contents of my matrix array...

Comment: @Raphael42 _"calling `matrix[4][3]` I expect to receive the value 0"_ - Certainly, that expectation comes from misunderstanding the ordering? Your _first problem_ is that you can't _"access the values of my matrix correctly"_. I verified that `read_csv_file` reads the file and populates `matrix` correctly. Since your first issue was based on the wrong assumption, I didn't spend time on the issue that appeared to be a result of that assumption. The matrix table I put in the answer is a product of `read_csv_file` doing its job. If it had been doing something wrong, the table would be wrong too.

Comment: Sorry, don't have the habit to go checking for stackoverflow notifications... Even after rechecking my code regarding what you said to me, I stii had the problem so I decided to change my method and instead of using a matrix, I used 1-dimension vectors to store each column of my csv file. It allowed me to avoid having to deal with the 2 indices. But thank you for your help and the update ;)

Comment: @Raphael42 _" I stii had the problem"_ - That sounds very strange. `read_csv_file` is doing the right thing. Were you able to verify that at least?

Comment: I know that the solution you gave me was the correct way to access an element of a matrix (I checked it by myslef). At least, with a simple matrix it is the good way, but in my program, maybe due to another problem somewhere else, unfortunately, the hint you gave me didn't resolve my issue (I had verified it) and that's why I decided to change my method.

Comment: @Raphael42 One thing that looks odd is your loop inside `choose_random_numbers`  The `while (!satisfied)` loop and the `satisfied` variable could be removed since it will only loop through it once with the current design.